# php How to check variable string?

Tags: php

I want to check few of IP address in the standard input.
And I've got error over and over....

> preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   /workspace/Main.php on line 14

I tried put string but it reconized Standard input is just one part... so result is always false....
How to make it work?

The result that I want is 
False
True
False
True

Right now I have this code.
Standard input :

```
4
192.400.1.10.1000...
4.3.2.1
0..33.444...
1.2.3.4
```

my code :

```
<?php
$input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
while ($input){
$array[] = $input;
$input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
}

$test = checkIPAddr($array);

print_r($array);
function checkIPAddr($ip){
    $result = "False";

    if (preg_match_all('/^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}$/',$ip)){
            $result = "True";
    }
    return $result;
}

echo $test;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second parameter in preg_match_all is an array. It can accept string only.

```
if (preg_match_all('/^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}$/',$ip)){
```

the $ip is an array.

Comment: Which also raises the solution, call the function within a loop through the elements of the array. You should also add one to your answer.

Comment: preg_match_all() accepts parameter 2 to be a string and you should pass a match string/variable to match with $ip. You are missing your match string/variable

Answer (score 0):

try small amendment in your code:

```
<?php
    $input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    while ($input){
    $array[] = $input;
    $input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    }
    if(checkIPAddr($array)){ echo "True";}
    else {echo "False";}
    function checkIPAddr($ip){
     if (preg_match_all('/^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}$/',$ip)){
                return true;
        }
    else {return false;}

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What did you change, how does it make it any better, does that fix the problem? Explain.

Comment: preg_match_all() accepts parameter 2 to be a string and you should pass a match string/variable to match with $ip. You are missing your match string/variable

Comment: But you still give an array to the `preg_match_all()`. `$array[] = $input;` It's still not a string. Closed anyway.